# C++ Functions (error: control may reach end of non void function)

Tags: c++, string, function

Sorry for bad english, i have beginner question about c++

I wrote a for loop to get all the letters in a string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string key = "apple";
    for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        cout << key[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

I was having trouble turning this operation (listing all characters of string) into a separate function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string stringiterate(string key)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        cout << key[i] << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << stringiterate("testing");
}
```

While this works, it gives me the error "warning: control reaches end of non-void function
      [-Wreturn-type]"

I understand this has to do with me not giving a return value to the function. I was wondering what the best practice for solving this problem would be. I have read other SO posts where the control breaks but I'm not 100% sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Why are you using `cout` twice when the function already does the printing?

Comment: Good point, I changed it and it still works, dumb mistake

Comment: Note that your `stringiterate` is pretty much equivalent to calling `std::copy` like: `std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, "\n"));` (where `s` is the string you want to print out character-by-character).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Or, indeed, just simply `cout << key << '\n';` It's not clear what the point is of doing it character by character.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: As-is, it's inserting a new-line between each character, which `cout << key << '\n';` obviously wouldn't.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Ah, right, I overlooked that detail. If anyone asks, I'm in the far corner, cowering in shame.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Oh, don't do that. I'm getting off work pretty soon anyway--we can meet for a drink and laugh about it. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function

```
string stringiterate(string key)
```

is supposed to return a `string`, but does not return anything.

Comment: Just change it to `void stringiterate()` and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

> warning: control reaches end of non-`void` function

This warning or error always means that you have a function that returns non-`void` (meaning something other than `void`) which doesn't have a return statement. If a function is said to return something it must have a return statement. In this scenario however I don't see where a return statement is necessary or even helpful. Your function should just have `void` as its return type:

```
 void stringiterate(string key);
```

Also, even if you fix up that code you'll get another error. This has to do with this line:

```
cout << stringiterate("testing");
```

`stringiterate` returns `void` and you are attempting to print it? This doesn't make sense to the compiler so it emitts an error for you. Besides, your function already uses `cout` internally so there is no need to use it outside the function's definition. Simply call the function by itself:

```
stringiterate("testing");
```

---

And lastly, `cout` already has the ability to print strings. How about just doing this:

```
std::string test = "testing";
std::cout << test;
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation, it is very clear. I want the function to be able to iterate through the characters of the string so I can do operations on the string, I think using a for loop is okay but probably not best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Because you say you are going to return something and then you don't!

```
int main()  // expects an int to be returned
{
    cout << stringiterate("testing");
    // Nope. No return statement here.
    // Try:
    return 0;
}
```

Same with `stringiterate` and your original `main`

If you don't want to return anything, the return type can be void (for `stringiterate` - main is normally expected to return an `int`). e.g. `void stringiterate(string key)`

Comment: `main` is special: flowing off the end is legal, and equivalent to `return 0;`

Comment: So, if I change the string stringiterate to an int, and add a return 0; there, is that good practice? I thought return 0; is implicit in int main()?

Comment: If you don't want to actually return anything useful, just make `stringiterate` return `void`. `main` is OK as written.

Comment: Wow I feel silly...void was so simple. Is void the recommended practice?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ...I did think as I was writing it that `main` had some special case stuff attached to it. Call me old fashioned but if you say you are going to return something I expect to see a return statement ;-)

Comment: @VladislavSkovesky `void` is recommended/expected practice if you don't want to return anything.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be looking somewhat like this.

```
#include<iostream>
void stringiterate(std::string key)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
  {
       cout << key[i] << "\n";
  }
}
int main()
{
  stringiterate("testing");
}
```